# Eclipse wont start after update

Tags: eclipse

Today Eclipse want me to update some stuff. There were different small things in the list to update.
After that I couldn't start anymore.

It always says there is an error and I should look into the log in the metadata.

The log shows the following text:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-11-29 15:14:02.900 !MESSAGE
> Anwendungsfehler !STACK 1 java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint
> violation: when resolving method 'void
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable.addBinding(org.eclipse.jface.bindings.Binding)'
> the class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader
> @8a6631b of the current class,
> org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/swt/util/BindingProcessingAddon, and the
> class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader
> @333d44f6 for the method's defining class,
> org/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/internal/BindingTable, have different Class
> objects for the type org/eclipse/jface/bindings/Binding used in the
> signature (org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon
> is in unnamed module of loader
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @8a6631b, parent
> loader 'platform'; org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable is
> in unnamed module of loader
> org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @333d44f6, parent
> loader 'platform')    at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBinding(BindingProcessingAddon.java:182)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTable(BindingProcessingAddon.java:169)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.defineBindingTables(BindingProcessingAddon.java:149)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon.init(BindingProcessingAddon.java:97)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:346)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:289)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:153)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Any ideas? Is there like a reset or the possibility to delete cache or smth?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your eclipse is corrupted now. Download the latest one.
Which version are you using?

Comment: It is version 2020-06

Comment: I mean version name like neon mars oxygen.... try download the latest one. sure it will fix your issue

Comment: If u feel my ans is correct. Pls accept it as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: @KarmaJ Note that current releases of Eclipse no longer have names, just ids like "2020-09"

Comment: Installed 2020-09 and now the bug again. Maybe deinstall everything and reinstall? 